# Bluemix Account vs. Bluemix User. Is there difference?

Tags: ibm-cloud

In SoftLayer, there's concept of Account and multiple users can be created under that account.  Is there similar concept in Bluemix?  Is there like Bluemix account that gets created then multiple users can be created under the same account such that when these users subscribe to new services the account gets billed?

I know that in Bluemix there's Organization and space.  And I can invite another user/org/account(?) to share my resources.  But can that invited user subscribe to a service on behalf of the organization that invited the user? (i.e. the invited organization gets billed?)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I think that you want to be sure that the individual is given the Developer role in the space. As stated in the docs, here is the definition of the Developer role:

> **Space developers can create, delete, and manage applications and
>   services within the space.** Some of the managing tasks include
>   deploying apps, starting or stopping apps, renaming an app, deleting
>   an app, renaming a space, binding or unbinding a service to an
>   application, view the number or instances, service bindings, and
>   resource use for each application in the space. In addition, the space
>   developer can associate an internal or external URL with an
>   application in the space.

This information came from this URL:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/users_roles.html

Comment: Not exactly.  I want to be sure that when I open an account and invite someone, that someone is part of my account so that if that person orders something, this account gets billed.  Or whether that invited person can order on behalf of the org that invited the person so that the org that invited is billed.

Comment: This is a question for Bluemix Support. Please open a ticket at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/.